# Custom tab bar on top of UINavigationControler

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to add a UINavigationController to an app I'm making with a custom tab bar. Everything works, the only problem I'm having is the fact that any controller pushed into view using pushViewController appears above everything else in my view (including the tabs). Is there any way to set the view index for controllers pushed into view?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question right, you want to display a UINavigationController's view for one of the tabs of your custom tabbar?

Comment: yes, that's right, UINavigationController seems to take up the whole screen, which isn't very helpful

Comment: are you adding ur tabbar to NavigationController??